# Import XML using SQL Server, the problem is it is returning only one record at a time and I want all records in one go

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssms

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @XML = 
N'<ROOT>
   <B2A>
    <B2A.01>
     <B2A.01.1>00</B2A.01.1>
    </B2A.01>
    <B2A.02>
     <B2A.02.1>LT</B2A.02.1>
    </B2A.02>
   </B2A>
   <L11>
    <L11.01>
     <L11.01.1>1123</L11.01.1>
    </L11.01>
   </L11>
   <L11>
    <L11.01>
     <L11.01.1>120001502140</L11.01.1>
    </L11.01>
    <L11.02>
     <L11.02.1>BN</L11.02.1>
    </L11.02>
   </L11>
   <L11>
    <L11.01>
     <L11.01.1>KDC</L11.01.1>
    </L11.01>
    <L11.02>
     <L11.02.1>11</L11.02.1>
    </L11.02>
    <L11.03>
     <L11.03.1>11</L11.03.1>
    </L11.03>
   </L11>
 </ROOT>'

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML
```

My approach

```
SELECT 
T1.be.value ('(B2A/B2A.01/B2A.01.1)[1]' ,'nvarchar(4)')  as [tcode],
T1.be.value ('(B2A/B2A.02/B2A.02.1)[1]' ,'nvarchar(4)')  as [apptype],
T.te.value ('(L11/L11.01/L11.01.1)[1]' ,'nvarchar(60)')  as [id],
T.te.value ('(L11/L11.02/L11.02.1)[1]' ,'nvarchar(6)')   as [Ref id],
T.te.value ('(L11/L11.03/L11.03.1)[1]' ,'nvarchar(160)') as [DESCRIPTION]
FROM    (
    SELECT  @xml AS x
    ) xml  
x.nodes('/ROOT/L11') T(te)
outer apply x.nodes('/ROOT/B2A') T1(be)
```

But here the problem is it is giving only one record at a time and I want all records in one go.

This is what I am getting

| tcode | apptype | id | Ref id | DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00 | LT | null | null | null |

and if there are multiple records then it should show like this

| tcode | apptype | id | Ref id | DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00 | LT | 1123 | null | null |
| 00 | LT | 120001502140 | BN | null |
| 00 | LT | KDC | 11 | 11 |

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @XML = N'<ROOT><L11><L11.01><L11.01.1>1123</L11.01.1></L11.01></L11><L11><L11.01><L11.01.1>120001502140</L11.01.1></L11.01><L11.02><L11.02.1>BN</L11.02.1></L11.02></L11><L11><L11.01><L11.01.1>KDC</L11.01.1></L11.01><L11.02><L11.02.1>11</L11.02.1></L11.02><L11.03><L11.03.1>11</L11.03.1></L11.03></L11></ROOT>';


SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T.c)
      ,T.c.query('.')  
      ,T.c.value ('(./L11.01/L11.01.1)[1]' ,'nvarchar(60)')  as [id]
      ,T.c.value ('(./L11.02/L11.02.1)[1]' ,'nvarchar(6)')   as [Ref id]
      ,T.c.value ('(./L11.03/L11.03.1)[1]' ,'nvarchar(160)') as [DESCRIPTION]
FROM @XML.nodes('ROOT/L11') T(c);
```

[image]

And for your edit, you can get the data like the following:

```
 SELECT T.c.value ('(./B2A.01/B2A.01.1)[1]' ,'nvarchar(60)')  as [tcode]
       ,T.c.value ('(./B2A.02/B2A.02.1)[1]' ,'nvarchar(6)')   as [apptype]
       ,T.c.value ('(./L11.01/L11.01.1)[1]' ,'nvarchar(60)')  as [id]
       ,T.c.value ('(./L11.02/L11.02.1)[1]' ,'nvarchar(6)')   as [Ref id]
       ,T.c.value ('(./L11.03/L11.03.1)[1]' ,'nvarchar(160)') as [DESCRIPTION]
FROM @XML.nodes('ROOT/*') T(c)
```

and then to use T-SQL to shape it the way you want. For example:

```
 WITH DataSource AS
 (
     SELECT T.c.value ('(./B2A.01/B2A.01.1)[1]' ,'nvarchar(60)')  as [tcode]
           ,T.c.value ('(./B2A.02/B2A.02.1)[1]' ,'nvarchar(6)')   as [apptype]
           ,T.c.value ('(./L11.01/L11.01.1)[1]' ,'nvarchar(60)')  as [id]
           ,T.c.value ('(./L11.02/L11.02.1)[1]' ,'nvarchar(6)')   as [Ref id]
           ,T.c.value ('(./L11.03/L11.03.1)[1]' ,'nvarchar(160)') as [DESCRIPTION]
    FROM @XML.nodes('ROOT/*') T(c)
)
SELECT MAX([tcode]) OVER()
      ,MAX([apptype]) OVER()
      ,[id]
      ,[Ref id]
      ,[DESCRIPTION]
FROM DataSource
```

Comment: I have just made some changes where I am stuck if you can review and tell me what to do for that then that will be great

Comment: This will help thank you

Comment: @SunilJadhav you can accept/vote for the answer.